# Only store results of "failed" celery tasks (Celery Result backend)

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task

Is it possible to only save celery results on specific parameters, such as a failed task?

I have been looking but the only way I could manage was to go back through the celery results backend and parse through the data outside of celery.

Is there a better way?

(Note: I am using mongodb as a celery result backend.)

Comment: If anyone wants to know, I just used a heartbeat to filter on tasks I wanted or did not want and removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of (do not take my words for granted). If you specify result backend, it will be used for all tasks both successful and unsuccessful that do not ignore results.